# how to make a canvas.drawBitmap disappear after a few seconds

Tags: java, canvas, bitmap

Hi I'm fairly new to java! 
I have a game that displays the level number on the screen as a bitmap. The bitmap stays on the screen throughout the level.

I wish to only display the bitmap on screen for about 2 seconds and then it will disappear. I'm just wondering can this be done. I've tried a few things but never got any change. Any advice would be much appreciated!

My code:

```
    if (theLevel == 1) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().level1, 1, 1146, null);

    }
    if (theLevel == 2) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().level2, 1, 1146, null);
    }
    if (theLevel == 3) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(AppConstants.getBitmapBank().level3, 1, 1146, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the time when the level starts and then in your if statements you can also check if less than 2 seconds passed. I am assuming you are clearing the canvas somewhere in the code other wise the bitmap will stay there even  if you don't call drawBitmap. I don't like this approach as it is not clean and messy, a better way would be to use a fade out animation that will display the level number then fade out after 2 seconds maybe, check out this [tutorial](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-fade-in-out-animations-with-examples)

Comment: Thank you Anthony, I will give it a look!